# How to pass a token to a protected route (a method in class) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am writing phpunit tests in Laravel.

I log in successfully into the application using the folloiwng code:

```
$response = $this->json('POST', 'login', 
      [
        'user_name'  =>  $username,
        'password'  =>  $password ,
     ]);

 $response->assertStatus(200); // This is ok and passes the test -- is green
```

I get the following results when I dd $response:

```
+original: array:5 [
  "status" => 200
  "data" => array:4 [
    "token_type" => "Bearer"
    "expires_in" => 7200
    "access_token" =>     "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.eyJhdWQiOi...snipped"
    "refresh_token" => "def50200eb65ae708701e58c732140ea2efca0083...snipped"
```

When I invoke a protected method called doSomething as follows

```
$token = "Bearer and I hardcode the access token above"

$response = $this->json('POST', 'doSomething', [
        'token' => $token
     ]);
     
     dd($response);
```

I get the following message:

```
 "{"status":401,"message":"Unauthenticated.Token invalid or expired. Please login or refresh token to   proceed"}"
```

Question:

1. How can I pass the valid token I received from the successful login to the doSomething method and all the other routes I want to test?

Comment: The Laravel docs probably mention this sort of thing already (have you looked?), but often such schemes require the token to be passed in a HTTP header rather than as a parameter in the request body. e.g. `Authorization: Bearer <token>` is a common format for such a header.

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you use actingAs() instead of hardcoding the access token?

```
<?php
 
class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testApplication()
    {
        $user = factory(App\User::class)->create();
 
        $response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('/any-route');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```